# What will happen to the Milky Ways nucleus when Andromeda collides with the Milky Way?

Tags: galaxies, space, milky-way

Andromeda will collide with the Milky Way in about 4.5 billion years. What I want to know is, will the Milky Ways nucleus reactivate when we collide with Andromeda, will it combine with Andromeda's nucleus, or will they both explode?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/197623/how-will-the-milky-way-andromeda-combined-galaxy-appear-in-4-billion-years?rq=1

Comment: thank you for letting me know, but mine is more specific while that one is general.

Comment: Latest research is that it will be a glancing blow in around 5 billion years. The nuclei may not merge for a considerable time after that.